# Why does the click event on the checkout page not work?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Example of a problem: [image]

The click event inside the form is not triggered

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('ok');
});
```

The most interesting thing is that the change event works correctly

What could be the problem at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In General, I found a problem, maybe someone will be useful:

```
$(document.body).on('updated_checkout updated_shipping_method', function (event, xhr, data) {
   $('input[name^="shipping_method"]').on('click', function(e) {
      console.log('ok');
 });
});
```

Instead of input[name^="shipping_method, you can add any class that is inside the form